# How to call a function with onclick in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I used this code to show tabbed content with navigate in URL:

```js
jQuery(function ($) {

  // Define Plugin
  $.organicTabs = function(el, options) {

    // JavaScript native version of this
    var base = this;

    // jQuery version of this
    base.$el = $(el);

    // Navigation for current selector passed to plugin
    base.$nav = base.$el.find(".tab");

    // Runs once when plugin called       
    base.init = function() {

      // Pull in arguments
      base.options = $.extend({}, $.organicTabs.defaultOptions, options);

      // Accessible hiding fix (hmmm, re-look at this, screen readers still run JS)
      $(".hide").css({
        "position": "relative",
        "top": 0,
        "left": 0,
        "display": "none"
      });

      // When navigation tab is clicked...
      base.$nav.on("click", "a", function(e) {

        // no hash links
        e.preventDefault();

        // Figure out current list via CSS class
        var curList = base.$el.find("a.current").attr("href").substring(1),

          // List moving to
          $newList = $(this),

          // Figure out ID of new list
          listID = $newList.attr("href").substring(1),

          // Set outer wrapper height to (static) height of current inner list
          $allListWrap = base.$el.find(".list-wrap"),
          curListHeight = $allListWrap.height();
        $allListWrap.height(curListHeight);

        if ((listID != curList) && (base.$el.find(":animated").length == 0)) {

          // Fade out current list
          base.$el.find("#" + curList).fadeOut(base.options.speed, function() {

            // Fade in new list on callback
            base.$el.find("#" + listID).fadeIn(base.options.speed);

            // Adjust outer wrapper to fit new list snuggly
            var newHeight = base.$el.find("#" + listID).height();
            $allListWrap.animate({
              height: newHeight
            }, base.options.speed);

            // Remove highlighting - Add to just-clicked tab
            base.$el.find(".tab li a").removeClass("current");
            $newList.addClass("current");

            // Change window location to add URL params
            if (window.history && history.pushState) {
              // NOTE: doesn't take into account existing params
              history.replaceState("", "", "?" + base.options.param + "=" + listID);
            }
          });

        }

      });

      var queryString = {};
      window.location.href.replace(
        new RegExp("([^?=&]+)(=([^&]*))?", "g"),
        function($0, $1, $2, $3) {
          queryString[$1] = $3;
        }
      );

      if (queryString[base.options.param]) {

        var tab = $("a[href='#" + queryString[base.options.param] + "']");

        tab
          .closest(".tab")
          .find("a")
          .removeClass("current")
          .end()
          .next(".list-wrap")
          .find("ul.me")
          .hide();
        tab.addClass("current");
        $("#" + queryString[base.options.param]).show();

      };

    };
    base.init();
  };

  $.organicTabs.defaultOptions = {
    "speed": 300,
    "param": "tab"
  };

  $.fn.organicTabs = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
      (new $.organicTabs(this, options));
    });
  };

});

jQuery(function($) {

  // Calling the plugin
  $("#tabbed-content").organicTabs();


});
```

```css
/* Generic Utility */
.hide { position: absolute; top: -9999px; left: -9999px; }


/* Specific to example one */

#tabbed-content { background: #eee; padding: 10px; margin: 0 0 20px 0; -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #666; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #666; }

#tabbed-content .tab { overflow: hidden; margin: 0 0 10px 0; list-style: none;}
#tabbed-content .tab li { width: 97px; float: left; margin: 0 10px 0 0; }
#tabbed-content .tab li.last { margin-right: 0; }
#tabbed-content .tab li a { display: block; padding: 5px; background: #959290; color: white; font-size: 10px; text-align: center; border: 0; }
#tabbed-content .tab li a:hover { background-color: #111; }

#etabbed-content ul { list-style: none; }
#tabbed-content ul li a { display: block; border-bottom: 1px solid #666; padding: 4px; color: #666; }
#tabbed-content ul li a:hover { background: #fe4902; color: white; }
#tabbed-content ul li:last-child a { border: none; }

#tabbed-content ul li.nav-one a.current, #tabbed-content ul#featured li a:hover { background-color: #0575f4; color: white; }
#tabbed-content ul li.nav-two a.current, #tabbed-content ul#core li a:hover { background-color: #d30000; color: white; }
#tabbed-content ul li.nav-three a.current, #tabbed-content ul#jquerytuts li a:hover { background-color: #8d01b0; color: white; }
#tabbed-content ul li.nav-four a.current, #tabbed-content ul#classics li a:hover { background-color: #FE4902; color: white; }


.page-id-642 footer, .page-id-642 header {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabbed-content">
  <ul class="tab">
    <li class="nav-one"><a href="#step1" class="current">Level1</a></li>
    <li class="nav-two"><a href="#step2">Level2</a> </li>
    <li class="nav-three"><a href="#step3">Level3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="list-wrap">
    <ul id="step1" class="me">content Level 1</ul>
    <ul id="step2" class="hide me">content Level 2</ul>
    <ul id="step3" class="hide me">content Level 3</ul>
  </div>
</div>
<a href="#step2" class="newlink">Go To Level 2 :)</a>
```

This code works well, but when I add a new link with class ('.newlink') in the bottom, the link does not work.
I want to navigate to step2 when I click on the link. Like when i click on "Level2" tab link.
Do I need to call function to navigate the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this:

```js
$('.newlink').on('click', function (e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#tabbed-content ul li a[href="#step2"]').click();
})
```

Comment: Sure, use something like that, but _why_ does it work? Why _doesn't_ the OP's approach work? How is this different from what the OP is doing? A good Stackoverflow answer should do more than fix the questioner's immediate issue — it should be instructive so it helps other people in the future who have a similar (but not exactly the same) problem. See [answer]

Comment: @Anish K. thank you for your solution. i changed a bit your code to a[href="#step2"] (just add #) and that's it work well. very nice solution.

Comment: @yasintaqizade Glad it helped. Also, edited as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

So, this was actually a very complicated thing!  *This may not be a perfect, 100% what you want answer* -- but it should basically explain what's going on and lead you in the right direction.

First, you bind `$.organicTabs()` to just `#tabbed-content`.  Well, the `<a href...>` element you have added is *outside the context of the bound element.*  I put the new link in a `<div />` and gave it the id of `links`, and then made the following update to the jQuery...

```
$("#tabbed-content, #links").organicTabs();
```

Next, your definition in `$.organicTabs` of `curList` needed updating to have wider document-scope...

```
var curList = document.getElementsByClassName('current')[0].getAttribute('href').substring(1),
```

Finally, to have your link connect to your tabbed-body, you'll need to move its scope upwards into the tabbed-body scope...

```
<div id="links">
<ul class="tab">
<li class="nav-two"><a href="#step2">Go To Level 2 :)</a> </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

***It works!***  The styling is certainly off, but this is clearly a massive project and not every little quirk can be perfectly readjusted so easily.  It may be that `$.organicTabs()` isn't so organic and fresh anymore and could go for some re-engineering!

```js
jQuery(function ($) {

  // Define Plugin
  $.organicTabs = function(el, options) {

    // JavaScript native version of this
    var base = this;

    // jQuery version of this
    base.$el = $(el);

    // Navigation for current selector passed to plugin
    base.$nav = base.$el.find(".tab");

    // Runs once when plugin called       
    base.init = function() {

      // Pull in arguments
      base.options = $.extend({}, $.organicTabs.defaultOptions, options);

      // Accessible hiding fix (hmmm, re-look at this, screen readers still run JS)
      $(".hide").css({
        "position": "relative",
        "top": 0,
        "left": 0,
        "display": "none"
      });

      // When navigation tab is clicked...
      base.$nav.on("click", "a", function(e) {
        // no hash links
        e.preventDefault();

        // Figure out current list via CSS class

        var curList = document.getElementsByClassName('current')[0].getAttribute('href').substring(1),

          // List moving to
          $newList = $(this),

          // Figure out ID of new list
          listID = $newList.attr("href").substring(1),

          // Set outer wrapper height to (static) height of current inner list
          $allListWrap = base.$el.find(".list-wrap"),
          curListHeight = $allListWrap.height();
        $allListWrap.height(curListHeight);

        if ((listID != curList) && (base.$el.find(":animated").length == 0)) {

          // Fade out current list
          base.$el.find("#" + curList).fadeOut(base.options.speed, function() {

            // Fade in new list on callback
            base.$el.find("#" + listID).fadeIn(base.options.speed);

            // Adjust outer wrapper to fit new list snuggly
            var newHeight = base.$el.find("#" + listID).height();
            $allListWrap.animate({
              height: newHeight
            }, base.options.speed);

            // Remove highlighting - Add to just-clicked tab
            base.$el.find(".tab li a").removeClass("current");
            $newList.addClass("current");

            // Change window location to add URL params
            if (window.history && history.pushState) {
              // NOTE: doesn't take into account existing params
              history.replaceState("", "", "?" + base.options.param + "=" + listID);
            }
          });

        }

      });

      var queryString = {};
      window.location.href.replace(
        new RegExp("([^?=&]+)(=([^&]*))?", "g"),
        function($0, $1, $2, $3) {
          queryString[$1] = $3;
        }
      );

      if (queryString[base.options.param]) {

        var tab = $("a[href='#" + queryString[base.options.param] + "']");

        tab
          .closest(".tab")
          .find("a")
          .removeClass("current")
          .end()
          .next(".list-wrap")
          .find("ul.me")
          .hide();
        tab.addClass("current");
        $("#" + queryString[base.options.param]).show();

      };

    };
    base.init();
  };

  $.organicTabs.defaultOptions = {
    "speed": 300,
    "param": "tab"
  };

  $.fn.organicTabs = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
      (new $.organicTabs(this, options));
    });
  };

});

jQuery(function($) {

  // Calling the plugin
  $("#tabbed-content, #links").organicTabs();

});
```

```css
/* Generic Utility */
.hide { position: absolute; top: -9999px; left: -9999px; }


/* Specific to example one */

#tabbed-content { background: #eee; padding: 10px; margin: 0 0 20px 0; -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #666; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #666; }

#tabbed-content .tab { overflow: hidden; margin: 0 0 10px 0; list-style: none;}
#tabbed-content .tab li { width: 97px; float: left; margin: 0 10px 0 0; }
#tabbed-content .tab li.last { margin-right: 0; }
#tabbed-content .tab li a { display: block; padding: 5px; background: #959290; color: white; font-size: 10px; text-align: center; border: 0; }
#tabbed-content .tab li a:hover { background-color: #111; }

#etabbed-content ul { list-style: none; }
#tabbed-content ul li a { display: block; border-bottom: 1px solid #666; padding: 4px; color: #666; }
#tabbed-content ul li a:hover { background: #fe4902; color: white; }
#tabbed-content ul li:last-child a { border: none; }

#tabbed-content ul li.nav-one a.current, #tabbed-content ul#featured li a:hover { background-color: #0575f4; color: white; }
#tabbed-content ul li.nav-two a.current, #tabbed-content ul#core li a:hover { background-color: #d30000; color: white; }
#tabbed-content ul li.nav-three a.current, #tabbed-content ul#jquerytuts li a:hover { background-color: #8d01b0; color: white; }
#tabbed-content ul li.nav-four a.current, #tabbed-content ul#classics li a:hover { background-color: #FE4902; color: white; }


.page-id-642 footer, .page-id-642 header {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tabbed-content">
  <ul class="tab">
    <li class="nav-one"><a href="#step1" class="current">Level1</a></li>
    <li class="nav-two"><a href="#step2">Level2</a> </li>
    <li class="nav-three"><a href="#step3">Level3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="list-wrap">
    <ul id="step1" class="me">content Level 1</ul>
    <ul id="step2" class="hide me">content Level 2</ul>
    <ul id="step3" class="hide me">content Level 3</ul>
  </div>

<div id="links">
<ul class="tab">
<li class="nav-two"><a href="#step2">Level2</a> </li>
</ul>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to change this line:

```
<a href="?tab=step2" class="newlink">Go To Level 2 :)</a>
```

Replace **$step2** with **?tab=step2**

Note: it will reload the page but this is based on you are trying to write the code. If you don't wants to reload then page then need to write javascript for the same.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Won't this completely reload the page for the user and bypass any JavaScript functionality altogether?

Comment: Yes. it will reload but this is based on his existing code that what he wants to do and corrected it.